# Django regex not matching

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have trouble matching urls using regex in Python/Django.

Here is the url it needed to fetch

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2017/11/3/1/
```

Here is the code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/$', views.blog, name='archive'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.blog_article, name='blog_article'),
] # regex
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The day `3` does not match the capturing group `(?P<day>[0-9]{2})`. Either change it to `03` or change the group to `(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})`.

Comment: @KuoChongYii You might also want to change the month to `(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})`, otherwise you'll have similar problems in January.

Comment: Doesn't work. Current code : url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1, 2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1, 2})/(?P<id>[0-9])/$', views.blog_article, name='blog_article'),

Comment: @KuoChongYii That looks like you have a space in `{1, 2}`? It should be without spaces. Otherwise, please edit your question with more details.

Comment: You know, I never realized that it would be that strict. I thought the regex parser would ignore the space. Feels like coding in C again where you have to write everything strictly.

Comment: I definitely will keep this in mind now. So many time spent for such simple mistake.